# Handling Carraige return in Filehelpers

Tags: c#, filehelpers

Am using the excellent FileHelpers library to parse a number of different files. One of these files has (some) lines that look like this.

```
id|name|comments|date
01|Abc|bla bla bla bla
02|Bcd|bla bla bla bla
03|Cde|bla bla \r\n
bla bla
```

And my class is like this

```
[FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth)]
public string Code;
public string Amount{get;set;} 
public string value{get;set;}
```

And i got error like following.

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

Please help me to fix this. 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please provide sample code and I'll take.a look for you.

Comment: And are you using UNiX or Windows files?

Comment: I am using Windows Files

Comment: OK then please supply a sample project with input file so I can look at this for you.

Comment: Still waiting on a sample or should I assume you have fixed and/or forgotten about this?